# OO Design Quality Metrics

Tags: oop, software-design

I'm reading a scientific [paper](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~alt/mestrado/oodmetrc.pdf) about OO Design Quality Metrics written by Robert martin.

In his paper he describes "a set of metrics that can be used to measure the quality of an object-oriented design in terms of the interdependence between the subsystems of that design"

He goes on about how there should be a good balance between abstraction and instability. Here are the metrics he writes about and how they can be calculated:

**Na:**  The number of concrete and abstract classes (and interfaces) in the package is an indicator of the extensibility of the package.

**Afferent Couplings (Ca)**: The number of classes outside the package that depend upon classes within the package.

**Efferent Couplings (Ce)**: The number of classes inside the package that depend upon classes outside the package.

**Abstractness (A)**: The ratio of the number of abstract classes (and interfaces) in the analyzed package to the total number of classes in the analyzed package. The range for this metric is 0 to 1, with A=0 indicating a completely concrete package and A=1 indicating a completely abstract package.

**Instability (I)**: The ratio of efferent coupling (Ce) to total coupling (Ce + Ca) such that I = Ce / (Ce + Ca). This metric is an indicator of the package's resilience to change. The range for this metric is 0 to 1, with I=0 indicating a completely stable package and I=1 indicating a completely unstable package.

**Distance from the Main Sequence (D)**: The perpendicular distance of a package from the idealized line A + I = 1. This metric is an indicator of the package's balance between abstractness and stability. A package squarely on the main sequence is optimally balanced with respect to its abstractness and stability. Ideal packages are either completely abstract and stable (x=0, y=1) or completely concrete and unstable (x=1, y=0). The range for this metric is 0 to 1, with D=0 indicating a package that is coincident with the main sequence and D=1 indicating a package that is as far from the main sequence as possible.

I made the following simple design.

[image]

I'm confuse about the last metric (D). If I calculate the metric D(D' in the picture), I get a negative value of -0.5. But if I read the description is says the value should be between 0 and 1. Also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package_metrics) states that for metric interfaces are also considered as abstract classes. But I can't make this up from the paper. Is this true?

[image]

Did I do something wrong? Is believe this design, although really small, isn't that bad right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If D is "distance" then you should consider its absolute value, the formula in the paper has an absolute operator also... I'm not sure how you calculate the distance, or I misunderstood you.

About considering abstract class and interface I think both of them are mechanisms to provide an "Interface Framework", which means keeping dependencies in the interface level not the concrete classes... so I think it's safe to consider them the same thing despite some differences.